# Find bounding functions by using Lagrange Mean Value Theorem .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that on the interval $[-2,4]$ the function is differentiable, $f(-2) = 1$ and $|f' (x) | \leq 5$. Find the bounding functions of $f$ on $[-2,4]$, using LMVT.
I solved it as $$-5\leq \frac{f(x)-f(-2)}{x-(-2)}\leq 5  $$
Which gives the bounding functions as $$y=-5x-9 \ and \ y=5x+11 $$
which match with the answer given.
But the other way
$$ -5\leq f'(x) \leq -5$$ 
$$-\int 5dx \leq \int f'(x)dx \leq \int5dx $$ 
$$-5x\leq f(x) +c\leq 5x$$
Although gives the same result after obtaining $c$ from $f(-2)=1$ is doubtful.

Beacause its not necessary that if the slope of the function is greater than or less than the other function then the function has to be greater than or less than that other function.
So the second method is incorrect way to solve the question. Isn't it ?

Comment: do you by any chance mean $|f'(x)|\le 5$?

Answer (score 0):

When you integrate, you should integrate from $-2$ to $x$, i.e.
$$
-\int_{-2}^x 5\,dt\leq \int_{-2}^x f'(t)\,dt\leq \int_{-2}^x 5\,dt.
$$
Then use the fundamental theorem of calculus.